# how can I see all of my grants in linux system?

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm a user in linux system , how can I find and see all of my permissions ? is there any command to see all of the current user grants ?

Answer (score 0):

Linux permission system is not role based by default but group based. To see in which groups you are, use id command:

```
id
```

Example:

```
tdi@blackstar ~/ $ id
uid=1000(tdi) gid=1000(tdi)  groups=1000(tdi),20(dialout),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),103(netdev),106(bluetooth),108(scanner),122(libvirt),138(debian-tor),147(kismet)
```